# How to combine two lists to get the following desired result containing tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-manipulation

I have two lists as:

```
a = ['apple', 'mango', 'pear']

b = ['ripe','raw','rotten']
```

How can I get the following result list of tuples as:

```
[(('apple', 'mango', 'pear'), 'ripe'), (('apple', 'mango', 'pear'), 'raw'), (('apple', 'mango', 'pear'), 'rotten')]
```

Comment: That's seems not difficult, could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I tried to use itertools to product it as follows: ```list(itertools.product(a,b))``` but it breaks the list a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list(itertools.product(a,b))` will use the element in the `A`.To make the full list as a element, you could use nested list,like:

```
list(itertools.product([tuple(a)], b)
```

Result:

```
[(('apple', 'mango', 'pear'), 'ripe'), (('apple', 'mango', 'pear'), 'raw'), (('apple', 'mango', 'pear'), 'rotten')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to solve by yourself?

Try this :-

```
c = []
for i in b:
    c.append((tuple(a), i)) 
print (c)
```

Comment: Thank you - I chose another answer for the variety they provided. But your answer was also very helpful. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The usual method is to use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [(tuple(a), x) for x in b]
[(('apple', 'mango', 'pear'), 'ripe'), (('apple', 'mango', 'pear'), 'raw'), (('apple', 'mango', 'pear'), 'rotten')]
```

If they don't have to be tuples, you can also use `zip`:

```
>>> list(zip([a]*len(b), b))
[(['apple', 'mango', 'pear'], 'ripe'), (['apple', 'mango', 'pear'], 'raw'), (['apple', 'mango', 'pear'], 'rotten')]
```

Comment: Thank you - I chose another answer for the variety they provided. But your answer was also very helpful. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in just one line:

```
[(tuple(a), i) for i in b]
```

output will be:

```
[(('apple', 'mango', 'pear'), 'ripe'),
 (('apple', 'mango', 'pear'), 'raw'),
 (('apple', 'mango', 'pear'), 'rotten')]
```

Comment: Thank you - I chose another answer for the variety they provided. But your answer was also very helpful. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
a = ['apple', 'mango', 'pear']

b = ['ripe','raw','rotten']

list=[ ]
for i in b:
    k=((tuple((tuple(a),i))))
    list.append(k)

print(list)
```